# Highlighting maximum value in Shiny DataTables

Tags: datatables, shiny

I'm using the latest version of shiny including version 1.10.2 of DataTables
I would like to highlight the maximum value in selected columns. Something like the example

```
options = list(rowCallback = I(
  'function(row, data) {
        // Bold cells for those >= 5 in the first column
   if (parseFloat(data[0]) >=5)
  $("td:eq(0)", row).css("font-weight", "bold");
}'
    )
```

If necessary, I could calculate prior values in a variable e.g maxCol0
but am not sure how to substitute this in for the hardcoded value, 5 as in above code

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could use `paste` to add the value of the `max` in the `rowCallback`:
For example, using the first 20 lines of the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(shiny)
df<-mtcars[1:20,]

runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    dataTableOutput('mytable')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      df
    },options = list(rowCallback = I(
      paste0('function(row, data) {
      // Bold cells for the max in the first column
      if (parseFloat(data[0])==',max(df[,1]),')
    $("td:eq(0)", row).css("font-weight", "bold");
    }')
    )))
}))
```